# Send multiple emails from using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a problem sending emails to a subset of addresses from a MySQL database.

It should be sending 3 emails (email1, email2, email3) but it is just sending the first (email1).

```
<?php
    $query_iscritti = "SELECT * FROM richieste WHERE negozio LIKE 'NOMENEGOZIO'";
    $iscritti = mysql_query($query_iscritti, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_iscritti = mysql_fetch_assoc($iscritti);
    $totalRows_iscritti = mysql_num_rows($iscritti);
    $mittente = $_POST['mittente'];
    $destinatario = $row_iscritti['email'];
    $oggetto = $_POST['oggetto'];
    $messaggio = nl2br($_POST['messaggio']);
    $allegato = $_FILES['allegato']['tmp_name'];
    $allegato_type = $_FILES['allegato']['type'];
    $allegato_name = $_FILES['allegato']['name'];
    $headers = "From: " . $mittente;
    $msg = "";
    if (is_uploaded_file($allegato)) {
        $file = fopen($allegato,'rb');
        $data = fread($file, filesize($allegato));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n";
        $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
        $msg .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
        $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
        $msg .= $messaggio . "\n\n";
        $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$allegato_name}\"\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
        $msg .= $data . "\n\n";
        $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
    } else {
        $msg = $messaggio;
    }
    if (mail($destinatario, $oggetto, $msg, $headers)) {
    } else {
        print "Errore";
    }
    while ($row_iscritti = mysql_fetch_assoc($iscritti)); 
    echo ("EMAIL INVIATE CORRETTAMENTE");
?>
```

I think the problem is in the `while` loop.

Comment: Please note that code indentation does not only serve ones optical pleasure. It is important for others to be able to understand your code if you share it, as you did.

Comment: You only fetch one row in the beginning and the loop at the end is completely empty.

Comment: A general note: you are using the outdated, insecure and deprecated `mysql_...()` functions. That issue is _clearly_ pointed out in the php documentation. You should port your code and start using `mysqli` or `PDO` _now_. Your code will stop working once you upgrade php otherwise.

Comment: You are adding headers as part of the message body - ie: `Content-Type:` etc are headers

Comment: where is your connection to the mysql server? (I.e. `$conn`)

Comment: You can use  `break;`  to stop a loop

Comment: Improved the English of the question

Answer (score 0):

I solved!
I replaced

```
while ($row_iscritti = mysql_fetch_assoc($iscritti));
```

with

```
while ($row_iscritti = mysql_fetch_assoc($iscritti))
mail($row_iscritti['email'], $oggetto, $msg, $headers);
```

Answer (score -1):

var_dump $row_iscritti and check what you get from database. If you have array of emails, then you need to loop mail function. Comment here dump result if you have still problems

```
foreach ($destinatario as $email)
{
    mail($email....)
}
```

edit:
you get email row at 6 line ($destinario), and you send email here:

```
if (mail($destinatario, $oggetto, $msg, $headers))
```

then you have loop started:

```
while ($row_iscritti = mysql_fetch_assoc($iscritti));
```

make it right, check what you have:

```
while ($row_iscritti = mysql_fetch_assoc($iscritti))
{
    var_dump($row_inscritti);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while ($row_iscritti = mysql_fetch_assoc($iscritti))
{
var_dump($row_inscritti);
}
```

dump gives me the correct array with all values of MySQL database